# Can I set remote HTTP proxy connection to Tor?

Tags: web-proxy, polipo

I have set Polipo to accept remote hosts and I made it go through 9050 (tor). Now if I use that proxy in my browser on some websites like whatismyipaddress.com I can see that I am accessing it through Tor Exit node, but check.torproject.org tells me that I am not using Tor, and I cannot browse hidden services. Can I access hidden services with this setup?
Here is my polipo config:

```
daemonise = true
pidFile = /var/run/polipo/polipo.pid
proxyAddress = "0.0.0.0"    # IPv4 only
proxyPort = 3128
socksParentProxy = "localhost:9050"
socksProxyType = socks5
```

And here is torrc:

```
SocksPort 9050 
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
Log debug file /var/log/tor/debug.log
RunAsDaemon 1
ControlPort 9051
```

Comment: Does check.torproject.org actually say that you are not using Tor, or that you _are_ using Tor but not the Tor Browser?

Comment: @Jobiwan It says I am not using Tor. It even shows my real IP address, while whatismyip.com shows Exit node.

Comment: What browser do you use and what are the proxy settings there?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with SOCKS 4a on Polipo config ?

From Tor FAQ, [How do I access hidden services?](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#AccessHiddenServices) :

> Some applications, such as the browsers Mozilla Firefox and Apple's Safari, support sending DNS queries to Tor's SOCKS 5 proxy. Most web browsers don't support SOCKS 4a very well, though. The workaround is to point your web browser at an HTTP proxy, and tell the HTTP proxy to speak to Tor with SOCKS 4a. We recommend Polipo as your HTTP proxy.

Comment: I tried that, same behavior. Do I need to set anything else other than socks4a instead of socks5 as socksProxyType in polipo config?

Comment: Don't know right now, i will try it later on my OS, can you tell me which distribution you are using?, also will check why torproject reveals your real ip

Comment: I am on CentOS 6. Not sure either why torproject reveals real IP! Is there some other website where I can check it?

Comment: check this ones: http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/ , https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ , http://www.ipchicken.com/

Comment: torstatus shows that I am using tor, ipchicken shows that I am connected through exit node but dnsleaktest shows my real ip. Strange. Seems that hidden services are now working with socks4a config. However I have dns leakage, right? How can I fix this?

Comment: it's weird, so in dnsLeak says Hello "real ip"? while in the others sites is the exit node ip showed

Comment: Yep, Hello real ip while others show exit node. Both my PC and my CentOS server are using Google Public DNS, if that matters?